# Spark SQL: Excluding the CURRENT ROW in PARTITION BY windowing functions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is an example to illustrate my question.

In this example, we are collecting a list of the other products that each user has bought, and appending it as a new column to the transaction table. (Also note, that we are filtering on some arbitrary column 'good_bad'.)

I would like to know if Spark SQL supports NOT including the CURRENT ROW in the PARTITION BY windowing function.

For example, transaction 1 would have `other_purchases = [prod2, prod3]` rather than `other_purchases = [prod1, prod2, prod3]`.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "user1", "prod1", "good"), 
    (2, "user1", "prod2", "good"), 
    (3, "user1", "prod3", "good"), 
    (4, "user2", "prod3", "bad"), 
    (5, "user2", "prod4", "good"), 
    (5, "user2", "prod5", "good")], 
    ("trans_id", "user_id", "prod_id", "good_bad")
)
df.show()

df = df.selectExpr(
    "trans_id", 
    "user_id", 
    "COLLECT_LIST(CASE WHEN good_bad == 'good' THEN prod_id END) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS other_purchases"
)
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found a solution, but it's sort of ridiculous. It involves concatenating the array into a string, and then replacing the instances of the current row's `prod_id` with `''`.

It is shown below in two steps for clarity.

**Code:**

```
%pyspark
df = spark.createDataFrame([ 
    (1, "user1", "prod1", "good"), 
    (2, "user1", "prod2", "good"), 
    (3, "user1", "prod3", "good"), 
    (4, "user2", "prod3", "bad"), 
    (5, "user2", "prod4", "good"), 
    (5, "user2", "prod5", "good")], 
    ("trans_id", "user_id", "prod_id", "good_bad") 
) 
df.show() 

df = df.selectExpr( 
    "trans_id", 
    "user_id",
    "prod_id",
    "COLLECT_LIST(CASE WHEN good_bad == 'good' THEN prod_id END) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS other_purchases" 
) 

df = df.selectExpr( 
    "trans_id", 
    "user_id",
    "prod_id",
    "other_purchases",
    "SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(CONCAT_WS(' ', other_purchases), prod_id, '')), '[ ]+') AS other_purchases_filtered" 
) 
df.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|trans_id|user_id|prod_id|good_bad|
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
|       1|  user1|  prod1|    good|
|       2|  user1|  prod2|    good|
|       3|  user1|  prod3|    good|
|       4|  user2|  prod3|     bad|
|       5|  user2|  prod4|    good|
|       5|  user2|  prod5|    good|
+--------+-------+-------+--------+
+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+------------------------+
|trans_id|user_id|prod_id|     other_purchases|other_purchases_filtered|
+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+------------------------+
|       1|  user1|  prod1|[prod1, prod2, pr...|          [prod2, prod3]|
|       2|  user1|  prod2|[prod1, prod2, pr...|          [prod1, prod3]|
|       3|  user1|  prod3|[prod1, prod2, pr...|          [prod1, prod2]|
|       4|  user2|  prod3|      [prod4, prod5]|          [prod4, prod5]|
|       5|  user2|  prod4|      [prod4, prod5]|                 [prod5]|
|       5|  user2|  prod5|      [prod4, prod5]|                 [prod4]|
+--------+-------+-------+--------------------+------------------------+
```